# jQuery custom selector- index is not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I started writing custom selector ( which does nothing) :

```
$.expr[':'].blabla = function (elem,idx,meta,items) 
{
  console.log(idx);
   return true; //just for testing
}
```

Run it :  ( I have 10 empty divs)

```
$(function (){$("div:blabla").text('3');});
```

but the console always shows `0` at the idx.

What am I doing wrong ?

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/oViMuJA/5/edit)

Comment: it seems to be a hard coded value `fn( elem, 0, args )` in jQuery

Comment: @ArunPJohny and why the f* is that ?

Comment: need to look into that.... just looking for some docs

Comment: may I ask what you are looking for ... you may look at the `:first` expression

Comment: @ArunPJohny learning to build custom selectors. like this video says ( plural sight http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvqyz.jpg) I know i can do the specific task woth another approach. but look at the pic. he does uses idx

Comment: I think in version <  1.8 it is working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jb3xd/2/ in >= 1.8 it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery 1.8 custom pseudo selectors were broken, and since 1.8.1 they recommend to use construction like below ( [link](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#note-that-in-jquery-18-the-old-api-for-creating-custom-pseudos-with-arguments-was-broken-but-in-jquery-181-the-api-is-backwards-compatible-regardless-the-use-of-createpseudo-is-greatly-encouraged) ) - use createPseudo from sizzle selector engine , and support backward compatibility if it doesn't exist:

```
$.expr[':'].blabla = $.expr.createPseudo ?
$.expr.createPseudo(function() {
    return function( elem, doc, isXML ) {
        //return true for matched elements
    };
}) :
function( elem, i, match ) {
        //return true for matched elements
};
```

Though, createPseudo doesn't allow you to get element's index, but probably you can workaround this using a counter.